# Combine a Mat map and a Normal map in Blender?

Tags: uv, normals, normal-map

So I have this model, which came with two maps: [image: Albedo and Normal] that I just now learned that the colored version its the albedo map and the blue one its the normal map, now, I want to combine this two into just 1 Map, Is it possible to do it? I've read things but none of them make what I want to do. 
The reason why I want to do this its because the software I'll (Pepakura Designer) use doesn't apply Normal Maps as they should. 
I'm hoping someone can help me.

Comment: Yes you can ,will try to post the steps

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes you can do that. I am assuming you are working in the Blender Render Environment and not cycles as their material workflow is quite different.
Attached is the file for your reference. The material is an old 3dsmax metallic material and the normals map has been generated using shadermap3.

[image]

For Blender Render workflow.
1. Create a new material on the material Tab on the properties panel.
2. Next go to the texture Tab on the properties panel.

**Settingup Albedo/Diffuse Map**
3. Select an empty texture slot and click on "New"
4. Select open and point to your Albedo map on your harddrive.
5. Under Influence Header make sure "Color" is checked.

**Setting up Normals Map**
6. Select another empty texture slot and click on "New" again.
7. Select open and point to your Normals map on your harddrive.
8. Under Image Sampling Header make sure "Normal map" Option is checked.
9. Under Influence Header make sure only "Normal" is checked.

Here on out you should be able to see the normals texture in the viewport in "Textured Mode". Remember to add some light source or else your scene will just be blackish and dark.

[image]

[image]

Happy Blending!

Comment: Hey, that improved the look of the object, I'm almost there, now, is it possible to "bake" (I think its the right term) and just have one uv map looking like it looks on the viewer? So when I use Pepakura Designer, I only apply one map that would make it look like it has the albedo and normap map. I have been using Blender for some months but I'm not so skilled, and I don't know if I'm using the right terms.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I was right, I baked and it baked the two of them together, now... I'm still messing with the mesh and all of that, final details, but now I can't seem to see the object when in texture view, now it all looks grey, and before I could see the texture if i just selected the uv map...¿? Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: The way diffuse map and normal map are interpreted by the software is different. When you bake the texture out, you are essentially creating a 2D texture map and the normal map are now static and no longer dynamic. Dynamic means that when I move a light source, the surface of the material reacts to it's angle and changes the way the tiny grooves and crevices react to the light angle.

Comment: The whole point of normals map is that it should remain dynamic when applying as a material. With that said, there is normal map baking which is for another purpose really. Usually, baking normals are done for the purpose of transferring a high polygonal detailed model surface to a low polygonal version. Often used in the game industry. Because of real-time 3d games, models needs to have really low polycount ... but in order for them to look good, normal map are baked and apply on the model so the game engine knows how to interpret its surface.